# Freeform upload error: The file could not be written to disk

Tags: solspace-freeform

My client uses Freeform Pro to take resumés and cover letters through a lengthy career registration page. After working fine for two months, applicants started getting this error:

The form you submitted contains the following errors

- The file could not be written to disk.

They only have about 10 megs of files in the upload folder, and have collected 274 documents already through this Freeform Pro form. I was able to upload files through FTP to the upload destination, so it doesn't seem to be a server limit. They are using EE 2.6.1 and Freeform Pro 4.1.3

Is there limit in ExpressionEngine, Freeform Pro, or the server that can be changed to allow uploads to continue? What might be causing this?

Edit: After further investigation, I found the problem appeared only for logged out users. If I was logged in, I had no problem uploading files through the form. This indicated the problem was not a hidden limit setting.

Comment: My guess is that you might be out of disk space, or that the permissions on the directory need to be reset. I imagine the file is being uploaded fine, it just can't be saved from memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more investigation, I reviewed the settings for the upload field. Once I checked this previously unnecessary option, the problem disappeared.

> **Disable XSS Clean**
>   This option allows you to disable system XSS cleaning just for this file upload field in case you are having issues with user uploads being incorrectly blocked.

While I can't be sure, and the hosting company denies it, I suspect they changed a setting or upgraded software causing XSS cleaning to become a problem.

Comment: never seen XSS cleaning before but seemed to work for me too

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before too where the client had reached the disk storage limit on their hosting account. Upgrading hosting or clearing out some old files to free up storage might help.